# How to build a native java spring from spring boot app to git registry?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, github-package-registry

I was following this [tutorial](https://www.codecentric.de/wissens-hub/blog/spring-boot-flyio) to upload a spring boot app as a package to github registry. In this tutorial, on the bottom of the page you can see a packaging of the app in the java-native form like this:

```
pack build ghcr.io/jonashackt/spring-boot-flyio:latest \
    --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny \
    --buildpack paketo-buildpacks/java-native-image@5.12.0 \
    --path . \
    --env "BP_JVM_VERSION=17" \
    --env "BP_NATIVE_IMAGE=true" \
    --cache-image ghcr.io/jonashackt/spring-boot-flyio-paketo-cache-image:latest \
    --publish
```

After some trial & error, I found out that `paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny` is deprecated and I used `paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy`. Now, my problem is that even though the package is uploaded, when I run it with `docker run link/to/registry`, the spring boot app stops immediately, like this:

[image]

this is the script i ran:

```
pack build ghcr.io/dragosp33/hello-world-native:latest --builder paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-tiny --buildpack paketo-buildpacks/java-native-image --path . --env "BP_JVM_VERSION=17" --env "BP_NATIVE_IMAGE=true" --publish
```

However, if I don't use the `paketo-buildpacks/java-native-image` and resort to simple:

```
pack build ghcr.io/dragosp33/second-hello-world-non-native:latest --builder paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-tiny --publish
```

I can go with `docker run -p 8080:8080 ghcr.io/dragosp33/second-hello-world-non-native:latest` and the app starts and runs on port 8080.

Here is my spring boot application pom.xml ( is the only file that seems important, the entire app is just a hello world app )

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo44</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo44</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-tiny:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Using the `jammy` builder is definitely the right thing to do. It should not be necessary to specify the buildpack explicitly. If you are saying that everything works when you don't specify the buildpack then I think you have solved the problem. Note that with the configuration you have here you should be able to run `mvn spring-boot:build-image` to generate the image instead of using `pack`.